# getting nan values after computing mean

Tags: matlab, matrix

the program bellow runs just fine but at some point after computing the mean for every column of the matrix and subtracting them from rows. I do get some NAN values (last 600 rows of the matrix patch) i can't figure out where the problem is. Thanks for hint.

```
           nPatchSize = 9;
           %%
fprintf('Loading data ...')
if(~exist('imagedata.mat','file'))
   filePattern = 'C:\File\my_file';
category_list = dir(filePattern);
numbClasses = 0;
numImagesPerScene = 100;
numPatchesPerImage = 20;
patch = nan(15*numImagesPerScene*numPatchesPerImage, nPatchSize*nPatchSize);

counter = 1;
for tempCounter = (1:length(category_list))
    if(category_list(tempCounter).isdir)
        switch(category_list(tempCounter).name)
            case {'.','..'}
            otherwise
                numbClasses = numbClasses + 1;
                imageList = dir(strcat(filePattern,'\', category_list(tempCounter).name));
                %                     for tempCounter1 = (1:length(imageList));
                for tempCounter1 = (1:numImagesPerScene);
                    if(~imageList(tempCounter1).isdir)
                        imageName = strcat(filePattern,'\', category_list(tempCounter).name, '\', imageList(tempCounter1).name);
                        myImage = imread(imageName);
                        if(size(myImage,3)==3)
                            myImage = rgb2gray(myImage);
                        end
                        myImage = double(myImage)/255;
                        %myImage = imresize (myImage, S);
                        for temp = 1:numPatchesPerImage
                            randStaCol = randi([1 size(myImage,1)-nPatchSize+1]);% extracting random patches from image (colum)
                            randStaRow = randi([1 size(myImage,2)-nPatchSize+1]);% extracting random patches from image (row)
                            tmp  = myImage(randStaCol:randStaCol+nPatchSize-1, randStaRow:randStaRow+nPatchSize-1);    
                            patch(counter, :) = tmp(:)';
                            counter = counter + 1;
                        end
                        %bmTrainXbin = [bmTrainXbin; myImage(:)'];
                       % label = [label;numbClasses];
                    end
                end
        end
    end
end
save('imagedata.mat','patch')
  else
load('imagedata.mat')
  end
   fprintf('done\n')
  %%
  patch = bsxfun(@minus, patch, mean(patch,1));
```

At the end when checking patch which is my final matrix it gives me only NAN values.

Comment: look at your variable patch, and see if there are any NaNs in there? If there are, look at variable tmp and see if there is a process that could generate NaN i.e. divide by zero or some sort of adding string or char.

Comment: yes, i have found my mistake, they come from the two extra folders i have added in my category list. thanks a lot.